# python psutil psutil.get_process_list() error

Tags: python, psutil

Im trying to do some things with python psutil but get a strange error.

```
procs = psutil.get_process_list()
```

Gets me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_process_list'
```

The only thing i found about it was this:
https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/524

But no real solution besides pasting it to another directory (which I tried but is not working for me). Does anyone has a clue why I get this error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After checking the documentation [here](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#functions) , I do not see a `get_process_list()` function in psutil, it has been deprecated according to [this](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/master/HISTORY.rst#050---2012-06-27) .

Maybe you should try the function - `process_iter()` - documentation [here](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.process_iter)

It yields an iterator that would return all the processes in the system as Process class objects.

You can then use `list(..)` to convert them to a list (If list is what you really want) , or directly use the iterator in a for loop, if you just want to iterate over them (If you just want to iterate over them one by one, converting to list would be an unnecessary overhead).

Example -

```
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    <do your logic>
```

Or if you want the list -

```
procs = list(psutil.process_iter())
```

Comment: Welcome :) , glad to be of help.

Answer (score 2):

According to [`HISTORY.rst`](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/master/HISTORY.rst#050---2012-06-27),

> #273: psutil.get_process_list() is deprecated.

Use `psutil.process_iter()` instead:

```
procs = list(psutil.process_iter())
```