# JSON ValueError in CMS, tornado

Tags: python, json, content-management-system

I'm tring to run Contest Management System ([docs](http://cms.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2/index.html)) in Ubuntu 16.04.
CMS runs quite OK, but sometimes it returns error, like this in short:

```
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

I'm afraid if make everything wrong by editing the code in packages, so please avoid such methods.

Here's the error message 
In the cmsAdminWebServer:

```
2016/08/19 22:39:55 - ERROR [AdminWebServer,0] Cannot decode score type parameters.
ValueError('No JSON object could be decoded',).
2016/08/19 22:39:55 - ERROR [AdminWebServer,0] Uncaught exception GET /user/3 (127.0.0.1)
HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='127.0.0.1:8889', method='GET', uri='/user/3', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='127.0.0.1', headers={'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1', 'Host': '127.0.0.1:8889', 'Cookie': 'unread_count="2|1:0|10:1471613726|12:unread_count|4:MA==|cb62dfe311f2b0bb4378ad4ba752764da4e2f88314a3aa76969aeec5ba764733"; login="2|1:0|10:1471612630|5:login|68:KFZ5aHVucm9oCnAwClZxd2VydHl1aQpwMQpGMTQ3MTYxMjYzMC44MTA1NzgKdHAyCi4=|a94f16138a54068f9eccc9e2950e7e079ff0523475d8c7f3dde9a2cc0048870b"', 'Referer': 'http://127.0.0.1:8889/userlist/2', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0'})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1332, in _execute
    result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms-1.2.0-py2.7.egg/cms/server/AdminWebServer.py", line 1687, in get
    self.render("user.html", **self.r_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 665, in render
    html = self.render_string(template_name, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 772, in render_string
    return t.generate(**namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/template.py", line 278, in generate
    return execute()
  File "user_html.generated.py", line 375, in _tt_execute
    score_type = get_score_type(dataset=dataset)  # user.html:62 (via base.html:129)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms-1.2.0-py2.7.egg/cms/grading/scoretypes/__init__.py", line 77, in get_score_type
    parameters = json.loads(parameters)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
2016/08/19 22:39:55 - ERROR [AdminWebServer,0] Uncaught exception (ValueError('No JSON object could be decoded',)) while processing a request: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1332, in _execute
    result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms-1.2.0-py2.7.egg/cms/server/AdminWebServer.py", line 1687, in get
    self.render("user.html", **self.r_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 665, in render
    html = self.render_string(template_name, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 772, in render_string
    return t.generate(**namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/template.py", line 278, in generate
    return execute()
  File "user_html.generated.py", line 375, in _tt_execute
    score_type = get_score_type(dataset=dataset)  # user.html:62 (via base.html:129)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms-1.2.0-py2.7.egg/cms/grading/scoretypes/__init__.py", line 77, in get_score_type
    parameters = json.loads(parameters)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

2016/08/19 22:39:55 - ERROR [AdminWebServer,0] 500 GET /user/3 (127.0.0.1) 35.83ms
127.0.0.1 - - [2016-08-19 22:39:55] "GET /user/3 HTTP/1.1" 500 4235 0.037082
```

It occurs when I try to see any user's profile

In the cmsContestWebServer :

```
2016/08/19 22:45:24 - ERROR [ContestWebServer,0] Cannot decode score type parameters.
ValueError('No JSON object could be decoded',).
```

and

```
2016/08/19 22:45:26 - ERROR [ContestWebServer,0] Cannot decode score type parameters.
ValueError('No JSON object could be decoded',).
2016/08/19 22:45:26 - ERROR [ContestWebServer,0] Uncaught exception GET /tasks/Hello/submissions/3 (127.0.0.1)
HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='127.0.0.1:8888', method='GET', uri='/tasks/Hello/submissions/3', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='127.0.0.1', headers={'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0', 'Host': '127.0.0.1:8888', 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', 'Referer': 'http://127.0.0.1:8888/tasks/Hello/submissions', 'Cookie': 'unread_count="2|1:0|10:1471614324|12:unread_count|4:MA==|29d9493cc5372707a208c1eca6f791069159c152d0afaf5faeba8ed098391a04"; login="2|1:0|10:1471614324|5:login|68:KFZ5aHVucm9oCnAwClZxd2VydHl1aQpwMQpGMTQ3MTYxNDMyNC4yODA5NTgKdHAyCi4=|a2ea45df8688435985f9e1d5dacc23d4c37ae7ff7bf992ea0cb32e5e2f31f530"'})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1332, in _execute
    result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 2601, in wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms-1.2.0-py2.7.egg/cms/server/__init__.py", line 195, in wrapped
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms-1.2.0-py2.7.egg/cms/server/ContestWebServer.py", line 1283, in get
    score_type = get_score_type(dataset=task.active_dataset)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms-1.2.0-py2.7.egg/cms/grading/scoretypes/__init__.py", line 77, in get_score_type
    parameters = json.loads(parameters)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
2016/08/19 22:45:26 - ERROR [ContestWebServer,0] Uncaught exception (ValueError('No JSON object could be decoded',)) while processing a request: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1332, in _execute
    result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 2601, in wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms-1.2.0-py2.7.egg/cms/server/__init__.py", line 195, in wrapped
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms-1.2.0-py2.7.egg/cms/server/ContestWebServer.py", line 1283, in get
    score_type = get_score_type(dataset=task.active_dataset)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms-1.2.0-py2.7.egg/cms/grading/scoretypes/__init__.py", line 77, in get_score_type
    parameters = json.loads(parameters)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

2016/08/19 22:45:26 - ERROR [ContestWebServer,0] 500 GET /tasks/Hello/submissions/3 (127.0.0.1) 35.07ms
127.0.0.1 - - [2016-08-19 22:45:26] "GET /tasks/Hello/submissions/3 HTTP/1.1" 500 4775 0.035801
2016/08/19 22:45:26 - ERROR [ContestWebServer,0] Cannot decode score type parameters.
ValueError('No JSON object could be decoded',).
2016/08/19 22:45:26 - ERROR [ContestWebServer,0] Uncaught exception GET /tasks/Hello/submissions/1 (127.0.0.1)
HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='127.0.0.1:8888', method='GET', uri='/tasks/Hello/submissions/1', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='127.0.0.1', headers={'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0', 'Host': '127.0.0.1:8888', 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', 'Referer': 'http://127.0.0.1:8888/tasks/Hello/submissions', 'Cookie': 'unread_count="2|1:0|10:1471614324|12:unread_count|4:MA==|29d9493cc5372707a208c1eca6f791069159c152d0afaf5faeba8ed098391a04"; login="2|1:0|10:1471614324|5:login|68:KFZ5aHVucm9oCnAwClZxd2VydHl1aQpwMQpGMTQ3MTYxNDMyNC4yODA5NTgKdHAyCi4=|a2ea45df8688435985f9e1d5dacc23d4c37ae7ff7bf992ea0cb32e5e2f31f530"'})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1332, in _execute
    result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 2601, in wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms-1.2.0-py2.7.egg/cms/server/__init__.py", line 195, in wrapped
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms-1.2.0-py2.7.egg/cms/server/ContestWebServer.py", line 1283, in get
    score_type = get_score_type(dataset=task.active_dataset)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms-1.2.0-py2.7.egg/cms/grading/scoretypes/__init__.py", line 77, in get_score_type
    parameters = json.loads(parameters)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
2016/08/19 22:45:26 - ERROR [ContestWebServer,0] Uncaught exception (ValueError('No JSON object could be decoded',)) while processing a request: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1332, in _execute
    result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 2601, in wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms-1.2.0-py2.7.egg/cms/server/__init__.py", line 195, in wrapped
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms-1.2.0-py2.7.egg/cms/server/ContestWebServer.py", line 1283, in get
    score_type = get_score_type(dataset=task.active_dataset)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms-1.2.0-py2.7.egg/cms/grading/scoretypes/__init__.py", line 77, in get_score_type
    parameters = json.loads(parameters)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

2016/08/19 22:45:26 - ERROR [ContestWebServer,0] 500 GET /tasks/Hello/submissions/1 (127.0.0.1) 56.84ms
127.0.0.1 - - [2016-08-19 22:45:26] "GET /tasks/Hello/submissions/1 HTTP/1.1" 500 4775 0.057471
2016/08/19 22:45:26 - ERROR [ContestWebServer,0] Cannot decode score type parameters.
ValueError('No JSON object could be decoded',).
2016/08/19 22:45:26 - ERROR [ContestWebServer,0] Uncaught exception GET /tasks/Hello/submissions/2 (127.0.0.1)
HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='127.0.0.1:8888', method='GET', uri='/tasks/Hello/submissions/2', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='127.0.0.1', headers={'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0', 'Host': '127.0.0.1:8888', 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', 'Referer': 'http://127.0.0.1:8888/tasks/Hello/submissions', 'Cookie': 'unread_count="2|1:0|10:1471614324|12:unread_count|4:MA==|29d9493cc5372707a208c1eca6f791069159c152d0afaf5faeba8ed098391a04"; login="2|1:0|10:1471614324|5:login|68:KFZ5aHVucm9oCnAwClZxd2VydHl1aQpwMQpGMTQ3MTYxNDMyNC4yODA5NTgKdHAyCi4=|a2ea45df8688435985f9e1d5dacc23d4c37ae7ff7bf992ea0cb32e5e2f31f530"'})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1332, in _execute
    result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 2601, in wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms-1.2.0-py2.7.egg/cms/server/__init__.py", line 195, in wrapped
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms-1.2.0-py2.7.egg/cms/server/ContestWebServer.py", line 1283, in get
    score_type = get_score_type(dataset=task.active_dataset)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms-1.2.0-py2.7.egg/cms/grading/scoretypes/__init__.py", line 77, in get_score_type
    parameters = json.loads(parameters)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
2016/08/19 22:45:26 - ERROR [ContestWebServer,0] Uncaught exception (ValueError('No JSON object could be decoded',)) while processing a request: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1332, in _execute
    result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 2601, in wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms-1.2.0-py2.7.egg/cms/server/__init__.py", line 195, in wrapped
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms-1.2.0-py2.7.egg/cms/server/ContestWebServer.py", line 1283, in get
    score_type = get_score_type(dataset=task.active_dataset)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms-1.2.0-py2.7.egg/cms/grading/scoretypes/__init__.py", line 77, in get_score_type
    parameters = json.loads(parameters)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

2016/08/19 22:45:26 - ERROR [ContestWebServer,0] 500 GET /tasks/Hello/submissions/2 (127.0.0.1) 63.60ms
127.0.0.1 - - [2016-08-19 22:45:26] "GET /tasks/Hello/submissions/2 HTTP/1.1" 500 4775 0.064078
```

when I try to see my submissions as a user, this happens and the score doesn't show up.

Here's the versions:

```
$ pip list
backport-ipaddress (0.1)
backports-abc (0.4)
backports.ssl-match-hostname (3.5.0.1)
certifi (2016.8.8)
cms (1.2.0)
coverage (4.2)
Django (1.10)
djrill (2.1.0)
funcsigs (1.0.2)
gevent (1.1.2)
greenlet (0.4.10)
mechanize (0.2.5)
mock (2.0.0)
netifaces (0.10.4)
patool (1.12)
pbr (1.10.0)
pip (8.1.2)
psutil (0.6.1)
pyasn (1.5.0b7)
pyasn1 (0.1.9)
pycrypto (2.6.1)
pytz (2014.10)
PyYAML (3.10)
requests (2.11.0)
setuptools (25.2.0)
singledispatch (3.4.0.3)
six (1.10.0)
SQLAlchemy (0.6.0)
tornado (4.0)
Werkzeug (0.11.10)
wheel (0.29.0)
```

I installed with this(in the docs):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential fpc postgresql postgresql-client \
 gettext python2.7 python-setuptools python-tornado python-psycopg2 \
 python-sqlalchemy python-psutil python-netifaces python-crypto \
 python-tz python-six iso-codes shared-mime-info stl-manual \
 python-beautifulsoup python-mechanize python-coverage python-mock \
 cgroup-lite python-requests python-werkzeug python-gevent patool
```

if you need, here's the requirements:

```
setuptools>=0.6
tornado>=2.0
psycopg2>=2.4
sqlalchemy>=0.7
netifaces>=0.5
pycrypto>=2.3
pyyaml>=3.10
pytz>=2011k
psutil>=0.6
BeautifulSoup>=3.2
coverage>=3.4
mock>=1.0
mechanize>=0.2
six>=1.1
requests>=1.1
gevent>=1.0
werkzeug>=0.8
pycups>=1.9
PyPDF2>=1.19
patool>=1.7
```

I already downgraded version of tornado 4.2.1 to 4.0, psutil to 0.6.1 from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216835/python-psutil-psutil-get-process-list-error).

If you need any list on this or if I'm asking wrong thing, please inform me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it was my mistake.
For who has same errors, (predictably nobody)
I filled my task scoring form improperly, so JSON couldn't decode them.
closing!